# Get elements of list beginning with specific letter

Tags: swift, swift5

I have a list of words `allWords` and I am trying to create a new list from `allWords` containing only those words that begin with a specific letter `currLetter`.  Looking at the docs, `collection.map()` seems like a great choice. However the statement below won't compile since `.starts(with: )` returns a boolean.

```
targetWords = allWords.map { $0.starts(with: currLetter) }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not described in the documentation of collection type instance methods, the solution is to use `filter()` instead of `map()`:

```
targetWords = allWords.filter { $0.starts(with: currLetter) }
```

Comment: It *is* documented, it's just the new documentation UI which groups things more and doesn't show inherited members. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence "Returns an array containing, in order, the elements of the sequence that satisfy the given predicate."